# Variable assignment with and without .innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript and curious about the following distinction I've just discovered. I'll use this page as an example. Take the upvote counter. It's class is `.vote-count-post`, and to edit this using `parseInt` I've done the following:

```
var voteA = document.querySelector('.vote-count-post')

voteA.innerHTML = parseInt(voteA.innerHTML) + 1
```

This successfully adds one to the vote counter, both as a return in the console, and within the DOM.

While observing this I noticed that `vote.innerHTML` occurred twice, so I wondered if that could instead be assigned a variable to avoid duplicate typing. Thus I wrote a new variable to test this:

```
var voteB = document.querySelector('.vote-count-post').innerHTML

voteB = parseInt(voteB) + 1
```

After entering this, the console returns an increase in the value of voteB, but it does not update the innerHTML in the visual on the DOM. I don't understand why, and wonder if this a fundamental/simple aspect of JS I don't yet comprehend. Could anyone help explain this?

Comment: That's because `voteA.innerHTML` is a direct reference to a property on an object. But when you store it in a variable, that internal reference is lost because that new variable is just the value of that property.

Comment: Try  `console.log( typeof voteA)` and `console.log( typeof voteB)` for clues as to why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`voteB` is a copy of the value of the innerHTML at the time you assign a value to it.
If the value changes, `voteB` won't update because it is just a copy of the value at the time of assignment. See [here](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600) for more info.

Comment: No, it is explicitly *not* a "reference to the value", it is a *copy* of its value.

Comment: @Alnitak I fixed it